# Does this "retreat" mean literally in "the *retreating* interpreter has imparted the director's messages..."?

Tags: word-meaning

Below is an excerpt from an [interview article](https://variety.com/2020/film/news/parasite-bong-joon-ho-interpreter-oscars-sharon-choi-1203505571/) about an interpreter who was accompanied at every press tour for the movie, 'Parasite'.

> From her first appearance at Bong Joon Ho's side in Cannes, where he accepted the Palme d'Or for his sensational "Parasite," interpreter Sharon Choi has been an unwitting award season MVP. Clad in minimal black and permanently clutching a notebook, the **retreating** student filmmaker has imparted Bong's messages of gratitude on the most coveted stages of Hollywood. After declining hundreds of interview requests, Choi shares exclusively with Variety the 10-month ride that began with a phone call last April, and ended two weeks ago at the Dolby Theater with a Best Picture trophy.

I just wanted to check if I'm right to understand "retreat" here to mean literally, "to move back and away from someone or something". (After interpreting a segment, the interpreter always stepped backwards away from the microphone, as expected from interpreters, to let the director or any speaker speak again.)

Seemed to me like there's no other interpretation possible, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Please give the exact source of the article quote, if possible with a link, but in any case the publication, the date, and author id listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "retreating student filmmaker" could refer to her stepping back, particularly if she has become known for that action.  It could be an error for "retiring" meaning shy or self-effacing. I don't see another plausible meaning.